# How can I Enable Microsoft Teams Sign-In and Notifications in my Web App (Node <=13)

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a web project, and I want to add a feature allowing users with Microsoft Teams accounts to sign in on my site. Users should be able to pick a Teams channel to receive notifications. However, I'm struggling with understanding the necessary workflows and dealing with SDKs. Unfortunately, I'm restricted to Node version 13, and most SDKs don't support it. Also, I can't use Teams Bots/Apps. Is there a way to use the Microsoft Graph API for user sign-in, channel selection, and sending notifications from my ExpressJS backend? The notifications/channel messages shouldn't go out from the user's end, but from my web api instead.
I can use the Entra Admin center to register new apps etc, just not Teams Apps.

I've looked into different SDKs, but they don't work with Node 13 and I keep running into conflicts, especially with the bots, which I had to completely rule out. I'm looking for advice on using the Microsoft Graph API, guidance on the workflow, any compatible SDKs for Node 13, and if possible, some code snippets to integrate this functionality into my ExpressJS backend. Any help is much appreciated!
I also looked up webhooks but again, I'm lost when it comes to authentication without SDKs and granting permissions etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to send the message/notification to channel but most of required to create a Teams bot.

1. **Using Activity feed Notification APIs:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications?tabs=http#requirements-for-using-the-activity-feed-notification-apis
2. **Using Incoming Webhook:** You can create incoming webhook but currently authentication is not supported for it:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?tabs=dotnet
3. **Using Graph API:** You can use Graph API to send chatMessage in a channel or a chat and it required bearer token, team id and channel id:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

**How to generate the token for a console app:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/quickstart-console-app-netcore-acquire-token

**How to generate the token for a SPA app:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/quickstart-single-page-app-react-sign-in

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I'll explore the options available, currently I'm thinking of upgrading to Node 16.